# use next Auth to store session at time of registration using email and password

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, next.js, next-auth

I am using email, password and username to register user and storing in mongodb. I want to use next Auth to store sessions at time of registration also. I want to redirect user in same way at registration in same way as user would logged in and session get stored. I cant seem to find a way to this a time of registration. Do I need to make user login again after registering to handle all auth related things using next Auth.

I am adding my registration api code.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import connectMongo from "@/lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/usersSchema";
import { z } from "zod";
import { hash } from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { UserSignUpSchema } from "@/lib/UserSchema";

let secret: string = "";

if (process.env.JWT_SecR3T) {
  secret = process.env.JWT_SecR3T;
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).end();
  }
  try {
    const data = req.body;
    const parsedData = await UserSignUpSchema.safeParse(data);
    if (parsedData.success === false) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: parsedData.error.issues[0].message });
    } else {
      await connectMongo();
      const { username, password, email } = parsedData.data;
      //@ts-ignore
      let existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ error: "Email aready exists" });
      }
      const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 12);
      const userObj = {
        username: username,
        password: hashedPassword,
        email: email,
      };
      const user = new User(userObj);
      await user.save();
      const token = jwt.sign({ email: email }, secret, { expiresIn: "1h" });
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "user successfully created", token });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json("Internal Server Failure");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using NextJS v13+ to create your web app ?

Comment: @Zanea the verison is "13.4.19"

Answer (score 0):

Since you use NextJS, you should probably be using the next/auth handler in your api.

create the file `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`
and use this inside :

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

  // Do whatever you want here, before the request is passed down to `NextAuth`

  return await NextAuth(req, res, {

    // NEXT AUTH OPTIONS HERE

  })
}
```

Generally, follow the steps described in the docs to get started in a fresh working way
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#existing-project

Answer (score 0):

Okay @zanea answer is correct but i will be more specific on how to go about it.

After creating the `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` file

Now in your `SignUp Route Page` or `SignIn Route Page`

import `SignIn` fuction from `"next-auth/react"` and send all the user credentials to nextAuth by calling

```
signIn(
'credentials', //very important, its lets  nextAuth knows you want to use your credentials and not a provider like "Google"
 {
   ... Add user crendtials like email and password
   callbackUrl: "/on-boarding" // callbackUrl you want the user to be redirected to after they finish auth
   })
```

Now in your `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`, you need to have include a CredentialProvider that will handle server fetching.

```
  CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentialPayload: any) {
                 // credentialPayload will be the user credentials you passed into the SignIn Fucn
              
               ...Now run all your mongodb logic here for getting the user token
                
                //Now make sure you return the data gotten from your mongodb Database, this should be what you want to store in the userSession
                return data;

            },
        }),
```

Next in your same `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`, you need to have add various callbacks that will help you in persisiting the session and also storing it.

```
 callbacks: {
        async signIn({ account, user }) {
        //Note that "user" will be the data value you returned from "CredentialsProvider", you are only passing the value down to jwt callback here
            if (account) {
                account.userData = user; // pass value down to jwt callback func   
            }
            // make sure to return true;
            return true;

        },

        async jwt({ token, account, trigger, session }) {
            // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
            if (account) {
                  if (account.provider === "credentials") { // make sure its credentialsProvider as you can have other Providers e.g "Google"
                    
                    /* 
                    Credential Auth is mainly handled in credential "Authorize" 
                    func.
                    you are only passing the value to session Token here
                     */
                    if (account.userData) {
                        token = account.userData;

                    } else {
                        token = {
                            accessToken: null,
                            isAuthError: true,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, }) {
            // Send properties to the client

            session = {
                ...token,
            };
            return session
        }
    }
```

Now for better understanding of the flow i would advice you also go through the docs https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/introduction and look at what each API does do you can tailor it to your needs